# Add data to table when pressing addbutton from my navigation bar inside a tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi i'm trying to add data to a MutableArray, that had worked before when I had the button inside my table. But now when I'm trying to use the right navigation bar button it doesn't update my table

The button is added from my Tab Bar, then I have 4 tableview classes for each tab where I wan't add data

This is my Tab Bar.m class

```
@interface TabBar ()

@end

@implementation TabBar
@synthesize tab;

MaterialTable *ma;
WorkTable *wo;
MilesTable *dr;
NotesTable *no;


UIBarButtonItem *addButton;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ma = [[MaterialTable alloc]init];
    wo = [[WorkTable alloc]init];
    dr = [[MilesTable alloc]init];
    no = [[NotesTable alloc]init];

    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

}

// method called when pressing the add button

-(void)add {

    if ([self selectedIndex] == 0) {
     // method in MaterialTable that adds data to my table
        [ma newMat];
    }

    if ([self selectedIndex] == 1) {
        [wo newWork];
    }

    if ([self selectedIndex] == 2) {
        [dr newDrive];
    }

    if ([self selectedIndex] == 3) {
        [no newNotes];
    }

}

@end
```

//END OF TAB BAR CLASS

```
    // My MaterialTable Class, the first tab in my tab bar
    //This is where I wan't to add data to my MutableArray when addbutton is pressed from tab bar


    // Method in MaterialTable to add data in my tableview


     - (void)newMat {

            alertMat = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lägg till material" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Avbryt" otherButtonTitles:@"Lägg till material", nil];
            alertMat.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
            alertTextFieldMat.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
            alertTextFieldMat = [alertMat textFieldAtIndex:0];
            alertTextFieldMat.keyboardType = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
            alertTextFieldMat.placeholder = @"Material";
            alertTextFieldAnt = [alertMat textFieldAtIndex:1];
            alertTextFieldAnt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
            alertTextFieldAnt.placeholder = @"Antal";
            alertTextFieldAnt.secureTextEntry = NO;
            [alertMat show];

        }

  add data to the table
 this method is also in MaterialTable class that is called when I press "Lägg till material"    which means add material in swedish 



    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        NSString *button = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if ([button isEqualToString:@"Lägg till material"]) {

            newMat = alertTextFieldMat.text;
            ant = alertTextFieldAnt.text;

            int i = materials.count;
            if (![newMat isEqualToString:@""] && ![ant isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSString *intoArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@endDate%@endMaterial%@endAmount%dendID", [ac getDateNow], newMat, ant, 0];

               // insert data to mutablearray
                [materials insertObject:intoArray atIndex:i];

                NSIndexPath *myList = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                [self.tableContent insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[myList] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            // reload table
                [self.tableContent reloadData];
               // sets data to my get/set class
                [ac setContent:newMat];
                [ac setContent2:ant];
                [ac setItem:@"material"];

          // method running in background adding the data to database
                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addData) withObject:nil];

            }

        }   
    }

    // method called to add my inserted data to the database
    -(void)addData {

    // add data to the database
    // db is a object of class (Database *db)
       [db addData];
    }



    @end
```

screenshot
http://i62.tinypic.com/2d0e5v6.png

what im looking for is a way to reload the graphics, table or the whole class.

I'm using [self.tableContent reloadData]; I have tried [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; /  [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];

It was working before when I had a button in the bottom of the tableView just above the tab bar that was called from same class

thanks in advance

I solved the problem really easy. I was doing wrong all the time because I didn't thought I could add the button from my tabs

I added the button in each tab viewDidLoad like this ->

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(newMat)];

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Comment: have you placed print outs to verify all of the methods are being called? do you know where it has stopped working, i.e. the add method is not being called, its not getting into the if statement etc.

Comment: yes I had, it is working all the way, if a switch tab and go back again my data is there. So my problem is that it won't show directly after I added it but it really is there, I logged the array exactly after the data is added and it shows my newly added data, so I think it only needs a graphical refresh in some way

Answer (score 0):

I sense the problem lies here:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addData) withObject:nil];
...
[self.tableContent reloadData];
```

I think the background update is happening after the tableView is reloaded. You should use callbacks to refresh the screen when the Update is complete.

Please also improve your naming convention. `ma, wo, dr, tableContent` etc etc. are very hard to read / follow for other people. Please name things after their purpose. e.g. `materialsArray, tableViewDataArray, self.tableView`

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addData) withObject:nil]; this method only adds my data to the database so it is saved and has nothing to do with the "temporary array", I have switched places on those two lines. This code worked before when the button was inside the view and called in the same class. 

I dont think some callbacks are necessary, I use try,catch inside the database class, so it will give me a message if it was not succeeded

 ma, wo, dr are objects of the different classes. And I will change them to longer/better names.

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt ok so this code is inside a UITabbarController ? ok in that case what is `self.tableContent` ? is that one of the tableViews inside another viewController ? if so I would imagine your problem is that this is not pointing to the tableView you think it is. I would imagine it should be something like `[self.ma.tableContent reloadData]` assuming `ma` is a reference to one of your tabs viewControllers

Comment: No, the the only thing I do in the Tab Bar Controller class is to check which tab who is selected and listen for the button. And when I press the addbutton it calls the method inside my other classes to add data. [self.tableContent reloadData] is called inside MaterialTable class

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt Ok none of this was explained in your question. Can you please update it appropriately

Comment: I have now updated it and made some more comments, thanks for your help Simon

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt in your tabBar class you are creating a reference to each class. `ma, wo, dr` etc. Have you just created these so you can call the method `newXXX` on them? or are they actually used later on to set the viewControllers in each tab. Meaning is for example `ma` actually pointing to the viewcontroller or is it another object entirely

Comment: They are objects of a class yes. Like this MaterialTable *ma = [[MaterialTable alloc]init];

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt no, please read my comment!. Do you use ma later on. When creating a uitabbarcontroller you have to give it references to viewControllers that it will display for each tab. Do you use ma for this later on or do you simply create it here, use it to call the method to add a new item and thats it. What it looks like you are doing is creating a second instance of the screen you are viewing. This second instance is making the popup display but it is this second instance's tableview you are updating, not the one on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question, where you can see that ma is a object of MaterialTable and is inserted in viewdidload of Tab bar. the other 3 are same but for 3 other classes.  I think everything but the refresh of the screen is working because in my for loop that is going through all the objects in my array are showing my last added item. So what I'm looking for is a way to force a refresh/reload of the graphics, becasue if a switch to a another tab then back again the item is there as it should

Comment: I have solved the problem now! I added the button from my tabs instead of adding it from tab bar. In each tabs viewDidLoad I added the button like this -> 
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(newMat)];
    
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt Ok you don't seem to have read or understood either of my 2 previous comments which is quite frustrating. I don't think that will work if you switch tabs several times. Please just answer the following questions, it looks like you are doing a huge amount very wrong and I need to correct it. `MaterialTable` etc are UIViewController subclasses correct? `TabBar.m` is a UITabBar subclass correct? Do you have a `UITabBarController` subclass in your project? if so please show me the code you have written to create it. If not show me the code how you created the screen

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt with the tabbar and the viewControllers. Please answer all 3 questions!!

Comment: This is my new Tab bar class 
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
@end

this is my the viewwillappear of a view in my tab bar 
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   UIBarButtonItem *addMat = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(newMat)];
   self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addMat;
}

Comment: @PhilipLeufstedt ok so you've posted code I can't read and have completely ignored everything in my last 4 / 5 comments asking you to simply answer my questions. You've asked for help and won't give me the information required to do so. I'm not wasting anymore time on this, good luck